# Looking for a fantasy anime series or movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I am trying to find a Chinese or Japanese anime that I watched a long time ago. The boy's parents die in their house during a fire but the kid is saved.  I think he tries to find the person that set his house on fire. He might've gone on a journey(not very sure). I think there are some weird creatures in the story and it was not set during the modern time. I remember a scene where he or someone else was on a swing and they were talking to something or someone in the sky. I am not sure if it was a movie or a series.

Comment: Do you remember when and where you watched this?